# Deallocating all memory space that the pointer to pointer points to?

Tags: c, pointers

I am confused about deallocating all memory space that the pointer to pointer points to.

For example, there is a pointer to pointer as follows:

```
int **p;                      //  +-----+      +-----+      +-----+-----+-----+
p  = malloc(sizeof(int*));    //  |  p  |----->|     |----->|     |     |     |
*p = calloc(3, sizeof(int));  //  +-----+      +-----+      +-----+-----+-----+
```

AFAIK, the right way to deallocate all memory space is

```
free(*p);
free(p);   // The order is unchangeable.
```

`void free (void* ptr)` deallocates the memory space that `ptr` points to, but p is a pointer to pointer, so why not use `free((void*)p)` to deallocate memory space instead of using `free(p)`?

Comment: Good, but the order of `free` is *not* swapable: `free(*p);` should be *before* `free(p)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void *` is generic pointer, i.e, it can point to any pointer type. No need to cast `p`.

Comment: Oh, I see. `p` is typecasted from `int**` to `void*` implicitly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"So why not use `free((void*)p)` to deallocate memory space instead of using `free(p)`?"

Because p is a pointer. A pointer **to** a pointer, I'll grant you. But a pointer all the same!

If you have a box for holding boxes, it's still a box. A box for boxes.

It would be outright bizarre if the rule was "All pointer types can be implicitly cast to `void*` unless they point to a pointer type"!

Comment: Do you want to say "... implicitly cast to `void*` unless it is a pointer type" ?

Comment: I don't think so. All pointers are pointer types! We're talking about pointers that point to pointer types.

Comment: But if you want to throw away a box of boxes you can just throw away the outermost box, not so with pointers...

Comment: @rubenvb: Very true. 
I suppose it's more like if you had a note telling you where your kept your notebook it would still be a note despite being a note about notes. If you threw the note away the notebook would be lost! You need to find the notebook and put it in recycling before throwing the note away!